# how can i put jquery on the laravel controller?

Tags: jquery, laravel

can i put jquery on the laravel controller?
because I need to use jquery to pull data from the database to the combobox, and the code view that has been created is placed in the controller

Comment: no you can't use jquery inside your controller

Comment: not sure what you want, but this can't be done, jQuery is a frontend framework/library, jQuery can't connect to database, I think you mean using `$.ajax()` to retrieve the data from the database using the controller

Comment: You could put jquery in your blade file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JQuery inside a controller, PHP and Javascript don't mix like this, both of them have different roles when building a website/app.

What you can do is to use JQuery inside your `blade` files and use AJAX to perform calls to your controllers requesting data. After that you can use JQuery to manipulate DOM elements based on the data sent by the Laravel controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write html with php code by concatenation. Same as you can put your JavaScript or jquery code inside html code by concatenation in script tag.

Example:

```
$phpcode .= "<h1> hello </h1>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() { alert('hello');});
</script>
"
```